# How do I read from a highland stream?

Tags: node.js, stream, highland.js

So I have a highland stream:

```
var getData = highland.wrapCallback(fs.readFile);
var fileStream = getData('myfile')
console.log(fileStream)
```

How do I read from `fileStream`? According to [the Highland docs](http://highlandjs.org/#Streams), there is no `read()` method on streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cause a 'thunk' - this can be done by using `.each()`, `.toArray()` or `.apply()` to pull data out of the stream. As you say, you can also use `.pull()` to to read one value from the stream. `.collect()` will not cause a thunk, but will batch together all the data once read from itself, if you want `.collect()` but forcing a read then you'll want to use `.toArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Wandering around [the docs](http://highlandjs.org/#Streams) further, `pull()` reads/evalutes a single item, `collect()` reads/evalutes all items.